# oracle wm_concat function breaks order by?

Tags: oracle

my query just like below:

```
select country, WM_CONCAT(name)
  from (select name, country
          from (select 3 position, 'alice' name, 'usa' country
                  from dual
                union
                select 1 position, 'bob' name, 'usa' country
                  from dual
                union
                select 2 position, 'steve' name, 'usa' country
                  from dual)
         order by position asc)
group by country
```

I want to get

```
usa bob,steve,alice
```

however,i got

```
usa bob,alice,steve
```

Any help with this would be great so thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Starting with Oracle 11.2 you can use LISTAGG (see Utsav's answer); for earlier versions there are other methods, for example using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH in a hierarchical query, which do not require the undocumented WM_CONCAT function.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in Oracle, the `order by` in inner query is moot. As there is not guarantee that the outer query will use/display the data in same order.

Also it is not suggested to use `WM_CONCAT` as it is removed from `12c` onwards. Refere to give URL.

http://psoug.org/definition/wm_concat.htm says

> WM_CONCAT is undocumented and unsupported by Oracle, meaning it should
>   not be used in production systems. The LISTAGG function, which can
>   produce the same output as WM_CONCAT is both documented and supported
>   by Oracle.

What you want can be achieved easily using `LISTAGG`

```
select country,
listagg(name,',') within group (order by position) as name from
               (select 3 position, 'alice' name, 'usa' country  from dual
                union
                select 1 position, 'bob' name, 'usa' country  from dual
                union
                select 2 position, 'steve' name, 'usa' country from dual)
group by country;
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested (because I am on Oracle 12.1, in which WM_CONCAT doesn't exist any longer, documented or otherwise), but:

- Remove the ORDER BY clause from the subquery; as you saw yourself, it
  doesn't help anyway
- Use the full syntax of WM_CONCAT:  `wm_concat(name) over (order by position)`.

Better: do not use WM_COMCAT at all; there are better ways. Which "better way" to use depends on your Oracle version, which you should always state when you post a question like this, on Stack Overflow or any other discussion board.

As an aside, get in the habit of using `union all` instead of `union`, especially when you are creating data on the fly like you did. When there are no duplicates the result is the same (and when there are, you probably want the result of `union all` anyway), and `union all` is faster, and sometimes much faster, because `union` has a lot of work to do to prevent duplicates in the result set.